# Cygwin terminal is only recognizing `pip3 install` rather than `pip2 install`

Tags: pip, cygwin

I need to install the python `future` module to compile a code using `./waf` command, and I'm doing this using the Cygwin 64 terminal. However, due to incompatibility issues I keep getting `future module not found` though it is already installed. I'm trying to re-install the module using `pip2 install` command, and the following error occurred:

```
Gover@LAPTOP-OV3886CH /cygdrive/d/ardupilot
$ pip2 install future
-bash: pip2: command not found
```

However, I can install the `future` module using `pip3 install` , but this is still not compatible with the `./waf` command. Why is `pip2 install` not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `python27-pip` and `python27`packages

see package contents on
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/python27-pip/python27-pip-20.3.3-2

Comment: Thank you ! how should I install these packages?

Comment: Using Cygwin Setup you can install any of the available packages. See User's Guide   https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages